# MySQL query parameters in a table field

Tags: mysql, join, select

Good afternoon.
I have two tables:

1 - table1 - (id, address, who_lives) who_lives field - text, comma-separated list of identifiers

2 - table2 - (id, name_of_resident)

composition of table 1

```
12| US Oregon    | 12,13
14| US Washington| 9,11
```

composition of table 2

```
9 |Petrov
11|Sidorov
12|Ivanov
13|Popov
```

How to make MySQL request, preferably via join, that the result was

```
US Oregon    |Ivanov,Popov
US Washington|Petrov,Sidorov
```

If possible, replace the comma with the br tag:  Ivanov,Popov -> Ivanov >br< Popov

Comment: FIND_IN_SET(), GROUP BY, GROUP_CONCAT().

Comment: But I'd recommend to normalize your data and avoid CSV in future.

Comment: FIND_IN_SET does not fit - only one column can be selected.<br>
SELECT t1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name_of_resident) FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t2.id IN ( SELECT who_lives FROM table1 t3 WHERE t3.id=t1.id )
GROUP BY t1.id<br>returns only one name

Comment: Your WHERE IN will not work correctly - it will filter the row for 1st element in CSV only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.address, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.name_of_resident SEPARATOR '<br>')
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON FIND_IN_SET(table2.id, table1.who_lives)
GROUP BY table1.address
```

[**<kbd>DEMO</kbd>**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af9e6b83537a5b1b70f7f2fdbacd87c8)

Comment: @antarey Remember - this is fullscan, so the performance will be bad.

Comment: Do you recommend creating another table?

Comment: @antarey Pay attention to **Andreas Wederbrand**'s answer. It is very-very useful. Your denormalized structure is so-so safe until the amount of rows is below ~1k.

Comment: I agree. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you design tables. Don't do comma separated listes. Do either a (foreign) key from table 2 to table 1, or a table with table1.id and table2.id for each relation.

Then writing the query will be easier.

```
create table state (
  state_id int primary key,
  address varchar(255)
);
  
create table resident (
  resident_id int primary key,
  name varchar(255)
);

create table who_lives (
  state_id int,
  resident_id int,
  primary key (state_id, resident_id)
);

insert into state values (12, 'US Oregon');
insert into state values (14, 'US Washington');
  
insert into resident values (9, 'Petrov');
insert into resident values (11, 'Sidorov');
insert into resident values (12, 'Ivanov');
insert into resident values (13, 'Popov');

insert into who_lives values (12, 12);
insert into who_lives values (12, 13);
insert into who_lives values (14, 9);
insert into who_lives values (14, 11);

select address, group_concat(name)
 from state
 join who_lives using (state_id)
 join resident using (resident_id)
 group by state_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7041f/2

Comment: No, so I said "don't do comma separated lists".

Comment: Thanks.
Your solution is correct, but I don't want to create another table.

Comment: How to redo a request?
I cannot change the structure of the first two tables                                             
 create table state (
  **id** int primary key,
  address varchar(255)
);
  
create table resident (
  **id** int primary key,
  name varchar(255)
);                                                                                                                            
  select address, group_concat(name)
 from state
 join who_lives using (state_id ???)
 join resident using (resident_id ???)
 group by state_id;

Comment: I figured it out. Replase using with on